# Error getItemCount() Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

> 6-06 11:18:51.673 2631-2631/com.example.user.helloworld/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.user.helloworld, PID: 2631
>                                                                             java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

I get Error line    `public class CarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarAdapter.MyViewHolder>{`

and line `public int getItemCount()`

I want to return more than 1 `(dataBeen and modelsBeen)`

How to fix it ?

thanks for your help ;D

CarAdapter.java

```
public class CarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarAdapter.MyViewHolder>{


    private List<Car.DataBean> dataBeen;
    private List<Car.DataBean.ModelsBean> modelsBeen;

    public CarAdapter(List<Car.DataBean> dataBeen, List<Car.DataBean.ModelsBean> modelsBeen) {
        this.dataBeen = dataBeen;
        this.modelsBeen = modelsBeen;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_custom,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.brandname.setText(dataBeen.get(position).getBrand_name());
        holder.name.setText(modelsBeen.get(position).getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataBeen.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView brandname,name;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            brandname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textBrandname);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtModelsName);

        }
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
    public class Car {

        private boolean success;
        private List<DataBean> data;

        public boolean isSuccess() {
            return success;
        }

        public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
            this.success = success;
        }

        public List<DataBean> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public static class DataBean {


            private String brand_name;
            private List<ModelsBean> models;

            public String getBrand_name() {
                return brand_name;
            }

            public void setBrand_name(String brand_name) {
                this.brand_name = brand_name;
            }

            public List<ModelsBean> getModels() {
                return models;
            }

            public void setModels(List<ModelsBean> models) {
                this.models = models;
            }

            public static class ModelsBean {


                private String name;
                private String detail;
                private int price;
                private int created_year;
                private String image;

                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }

                public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                }

                public String getDetail() {
                    return detail;
                }

                public void setDetail(String detail) {
                    this.detail = detail;
                }

                public int getPrice() {
                    return price;
                }

                public void setPrice(int price) {
                    this.price = price;
                }

                public int getCreated_year() {
                    return created_year;
                }

                public void setCreated_year(int created_year) {
                    this.created_year = created_year;
                }

                public String getImage() {
                    return image;
                }

                public void setImage(String image) {
                    this.image = image;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final String URL = "http://xxxx/";
        private static final String TAG ="MainActivity";

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private CarAdapter carAdapter;
        List<Car.DataBean> cars;
        List<Car.DataBean.ModelsBean> carss;
        private  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;





        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Recycler_item);

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();

                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    }).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            CarInterface service = retrofit.create(CarInterface.class);
            Call<Car> call = service.listCar();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Car>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Car> call, retrofit2.Response<Car> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse"+ response.body());

                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        cars = new ArrayList<Car.DataBean>();
                        carss = new ArrayList<Car.DataBean.ModelsBean>();
                        Car result = response.body();
                        cars = result.getData();
//and I want to show name in Car.DataBean.ModelsBean How to set it?????

                        carAdapter = new CarAdapter(cars,carss);

                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(carAdapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Car> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your dataBeen list size is zero. Check the size of your dataBeen list inside your constructor where you are initializing it.

Comment: post full code here

Comment: @quicklearner i edited a post please check for me

Comment: @sumit If I set only dataBeen (not have modelsBeen) is not error,But I want to show data in modelsBeen too :( // i edited a post ,please check for me

Comment: Didn't get you can you explain in detail the scenario when is your app crashing??

Comment: @sumit sorry my english is not good , I want to get name in modelsBeen and brand_name in dataBeen to show in app

Comment: that's ok your app is crashing here  
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataBeen.size();
    }
because your dataBeen list size is zero.Check the size of the your List

Comment: @sumit yes I know ,but How to fix it?

Comment: Here carAdapter = new CarAdapter(cars,carss); when you are initializing your list check whether you have received some data or not. As I see from your code you haven't put any data in your carss list and not sure about this line also cars = result.getData(); whether this is putting some data in your car list

Comment: @sumit I cannot put data in carss because I try put carss = result. is not have getName(in modelsBeen)

Comment: The way you are parsing your response is not correct. can you share the response you are getting.

Comment: `D/MainActivity: onResponsecom.example.user.helloworld.Car@24786da` what?! haha

Comment: @sumit please help me :(